# Why is struct int value not being carried on to the next function?

Tags: c, function, struct, binaryfiles

I'm practising how to work with binary files and playing around with storing, reading and printing out some int values. So, naturally, I've come across a little something that does not affect the functionality of the code (that is, for what I want it to do so far) but it bugs me because I can't seem to find an answer as to why it happens.

I've found, as you'll see in the code below, that if I assign 'cod.x' as a parameter in the function **'create'** (right as it is right now), then assign 'cod.y' to the **fread** in the **'read'** function BUT instead I set it to print 'cod.x' in the following line, I end up getting a sequence of 9s. 
Which makes perfect sense, it was the last int value assigned by the for loop in the former function.

Now, however, if in both functions I swap  'cod.x' for 'cod.y' (that's to say, I order it to print 'cod.y' expecting to see the sequence of 9s again) I get 0s, as I would (correctly, I think, since it's been unused so far) with 'cod.z'.

If in this second go I used 'cod.y' only back in the fuction **'create'**, why does this happen? Shouldn't the 9s carry through like it did with 'cod.x' before?

What am I missing?

(Funny thing is I found the 9s do carry through if I assign 'cod.z' (instead of 'cod.x') to the fread in the **'read'** function. Then, in the next line, I order it to print 'cod.y' and the sequence of 9s is there all right!

So, it sort of seems like a new function writing new data on a variable that 'comes before' the one used by the preceding function ( *x* is declared "before" *y* , *y* "before" *z*...in a way?) automatically deletes what the the latter variable had stored. I don't know if this is at all a relevant observation but I did point it out.)

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct nums{
    int x, y, z;
}cod;

void create(FILE* BinList);
void read(FILE* BinList);
//void change(FILE* BinList);


int main(void)
{
    FILE * BinList;

    BinList = fopen("handylist.bin", "wb");
    if (!BinList)   return 1;
    create(BinList);  //sequence 0123456789 is written in the bin file

    BinList = fopen("handylist.bin", "rb");
    if (!BinList)   return 1;
    read(BinList);  // sequence is printed in both ascending and descending order

    return 0;

}


void create(FILE* BinList) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        { 
            cod.x = i;      
            fwrite(&cod.x, sizeof(struct nums), 1, BinList);  
        }

    printf("Last stored value: %d", cod.x); 

    fclose(BinList);
}



void read(FILE* BinList)
{
    int i;

    printf("\n\nCopied Data:");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fread(&cod.y, sizeof(struct nums), 1, BinList);
        printf("\n%d", cod.y);         //here is where the problem happens

    }

    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("Values: x:%d, y:%d, z:%d\n",cod.x,cod.y,cod.z);  //checking struct values


    printf("Order is inverted:\n");

    for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        fseek(BinList, sizeof(struct nums) *i, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&cod.z, sizeof(struct nums), 1, BinList);

        printf("%d \n", cod.z);

    }

    fclose(BinList);

}
```

Comment: `fwrite(&cod.x, sizeof(struct nums), 1, BinList);` If you just want to write the one integer value then it should be `fwrite(&cod.x, sizeof(int), 1, BinList);`.

Comment: If you write from `cod.x`, why do you read into `&cod.y`? You will overwrite stuff that is not yours.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're right. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm not sure what you mean. I mean, I do have access to the struct as a whole. I myself decided I'd read the values into cod.y, there wasn't anything of importance there for the purpose of my program as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your reply to my hint, I'll provide more details here as a answer.

```
fwrite(&cod.x, sizeof(struct nums), 1, BinList);
```

Here you write from the address of `x` in the structure `cod` a number of bytes. You write the whole struct. There is no problem because `&cod` and `&cod.x` are the same because `x` is the first member of the structure.

```
fread(&cod.y, sizeof(struct nums), 1, BinList);
```

Here you read a number of bytes. You read the size of the whole strucure, that is you read an x, y and z. But you place that starting at `cod.y`. So you put there bytes for the value of y, of z and of ??? There is no more structure to place bytes! So the last bytes you place "in memory that is not yours."

```
cod.x   y   z    ???
+----+----+----+----....
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----....
        ^    ^    ^
        |    |    |
    ----+----+----+  read puts the data here
```